# Не запускается Docker на windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, install, desktop

**У меня операционка Windows 10 Pro 20H2**

При установке докер с WSL2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит ошибка связанная с деплоем WSL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**===============================================================================**

При установке Docker с Hyper-V

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бесконечно висит "Docker Desktop starting..."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительная информация:

- Виртуализация включена
- Hyper-V есть
- WSL2 установлено
- Перепробовал множество советов со stackoverflow  и других ресурсов
- Другие версии Docker так же не работали

**Как мне решить проблему запуска Docker?**

Comment: Перед установкой обновитесь до актуальной версии 22H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На операционке Windows 10 Pro версии 20H2 у меня тоже не заработал докер. Как оказалось эта версия урезанная (ограниченный набор функций) [ссылка](https://3dnews.ru/1013553/microsoft-sdelala-osennee-obnovlenie-windows-10-20h2-dostupnim-dlya-testirovshchikov).
На версиях 2004 и 21H2 докер запускался у меня без вопросов.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но лучше использовать версии винды начиная с 21H2, т.к. там появилась полная поддержка  вычислений GPU в WSL [ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-21h2).

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!
Установил винду 22H2 и всё олично работает.